# How to set the timeoffset in a Datetimeoffset column without changing the date part

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

Is there any way to set the `timeoffset` of a `datetimeoffset` column directly without having to use `SWITCHOFFSET` which ***changes*** the date as well?

In the post below, we can see the `SWITCHOFFSET` will change the date accordingly along with setting the timeoffset (which is not what we want):
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/15/sql-server-datetime-function-switchoffset-example/

For example I have the date value as '2013-02-10' and want to record it in different timezones, without losing the '2013-02-10'. Just set the timeoffset to what needed , e.g: +11, -4, -6, etc.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: If the limitations of datetimeoffset are problematic for you, do what I do: store UTC data and store tz info elsewhere.

Comment: ...or don't store tz info elsewhere at all, just convert at query time.

Comment: Well, I totally agree and understand your point to do it in presentation, but it is a requirement for our scenario, so I should do it in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up to achieve this by applying the time differs between the original value and the value after applying the SwitchoffSet, and then run the SwitchOffSet to create the Time zone offset:

```
set @datetime = '2013-02-07 14:28:10.123'
set @datetimeoffset = '2013-02-07 14:28:10.123' 

SELECT @datetimeoffset = SWITCHOFFSET (DateAdd(hh, -10, @datetimeoffset), '+10:00')
SELECT @datetimeoffset AS '@datetimeoffset ', @datetime AS 'datetime';
```

As you can see, the original date value is unchanged.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid the extra DateAdd (may be difficult if time zone is a variable), use:

```
TODATETIMEOFFSET(@datetimeoffset, @timeZone)
```

Answer (score 1):

Switching the offset will take into account the previous offset if it exists.  It would be better to cast the original value as a datetime to truncate the previous offset then set the new offset as needed:

```
TODATETIMEOFFSET(CAST(@OriginalDateTimeOrOffset AS DATETIME), '-06:00')
```